# UIview is not placed in screen center

Tags: ios

I expect to see my `UISegmentedControl` in screen center but it's not:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.segmentedControl setWidth:75 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.segmentedControl setWidth:75 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [self.segmentedControl setWidth:75 forSegmentAtIndex:2];

    CGPoint center = self.view.center;
    self.segmentedControl.center = center;
}
```

I already tried to do what is suggested in answers to "duplicate" question and it's not working. If this makes sense, view is created in xib.

Comment: Note: Not the accepted answer, but rather the answer from @Hejazi

Comment: You're trying to center the view in viewDidLoad. At this point self.view is probably going to have a zero frame, center and bounds. Try moving the last two lines into viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I think that is not the problem. I also create a subview in viewDidLoad. 
I would try: 
`CGPoint superCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([superview bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([superview bounds]);`
`self.segmentedControl.center = superCenter;`

Comment: @liamnichols. no, self.view.center is (160, 240)

Comment: @Watsche. does not help

Comment: @Nhon Nguyen. What you're suggesting is the same as i alrady did and it does not work

Comment: You mentioned wrong guy

Comment: sorry, it was addressed to trojanfoe.

Comment: @4ntoine No, I left a comment which mentions not using the accepted answer, but rather the most upvoted answer.

Comment: you marked the question as duplicate and it's not

Comment: @4ntoine Did you try the most upvoted answer in that question or not (i.e. the use of `convertPoint`)?

Comment: yes, and the problem was in "auto layout" enabled, not in the code